# $f$ holomorphic on $D\setminus \{0\}$ and takes no values in $(-\infty,0],$ then $0$ removable

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ is holomorphic on $D\setminus \{0\}$ and takes no values in $(-\infty,0]$ then $0$ is a removable singularity.

I thought to prove this by elimination, but I can't really tell anything about the behavior of $f$ around $0$. How can one translate the information about the definition of $f$ in semi-open interval $(-\infty,0]$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$G := \Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ can be mapped conformally onto
the unit disk. That is generally true for all *simply-connected*
domains due to the Riemann mapping theorem. In this particular case
the mapping can be described explicitly as
$$
 \varphi(z) = \frac{\sqrt z - 1}{\sqrt z + 1}
$$
where $\sqrt z$ is the holomorphic branch mapping $G$ onto the right
halfplane.

Then $g := \varphi \circ f$ is holomorphic in $D\setminus \{0\}$
with values in the unit disk, i.e. $g$ is *bounded*.
It follows that $g$ has a removable singularity at $z= 0$,
and then the same holds for $f$.

One could also use the ["Great Picard Theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) which states that
a holomorphic function takes on all possible complex values, with at most a single exception, infinitely often in a punctured neighbourhood of an
essential singularity. But that is an "advanced" result in 
complex analysis.

Comment: I am a little confused. What makes $g$ bounded? And what exactly indicates the existence of the removable singularity?

Comment: I am so sorry to have neglected this thread. It was unintentional and we moved on with the materials.

Comment: @Meitar: $g$ is bounded by $1$ because its values are in the unit disk. Riemann's theorem (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) states that if $f$ is bounded in the neighbourhood of an isolated singularity then this singularity is removable.

Comment: @MartinR It has been a while, but is there a simple way to show that if $0$ is removable for $g$ then $0$ is removable for $f$? I ask since I tried to show that $f$ is also bounded around $0$ in this case (which must be true if $0$ is indeed a removable singularity) but didn't manage to do so.

Comment: @dan: If $\tilde g$ is the holomorphic extension of $g$ to $D$ then $\tilde f = \phi^{-1} \circ \tilde g = \left( \frac{1+\tilde g}{1-\tilde g} \right)^2$  is the holomorphic extension of $f$ to $D$.